# CSS : Transition list to left when clicked on delete icon

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

I'm developing an mobile application using `ionic`. In this I'm trying to implement the delete feature like this :

[image: Delete List Items]

As we see there is icon on left-side of the every list item, when clicked on that icon, list transitions to left-side and delete button gets displayed on the screen.

I want to implement the same feature..But not able to write the right CSS. Please guide me how should I make this work.
Here is the link to my [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GK1tJPWiAg0C1dntNx91?p=preview)

Comment: [Is this it?](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionDeleteButton/)

Comment: @aug This is not what I need.. I want the minus icon to be displayed by default. And when user clicks on that icon, list should transition to left and delete button should get displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ionic list directive.

```
<ion-list ng-controller="MyCtrl"
       show-delete="shouldShowDelete"
      show-reorder="shouldShowReorder"
      can-swipe="listCanSwipe">
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items"
        class="item-thumbnail-left">

<img ng-src="{{item.img}}">
<h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
<p>{{item.description}}</p>
<ion-option-button class="button-positive"
                   ng-click="share(item)">
  Share
</ion-option-button>
<ion-option-button class="button-info"
                   ng-click="edit(item)">
  Edit
</ion-option-button>
<ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled"
                   ng-click="items.splice($index, 1)">
</ion-delete-button>
 <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon"
                    on-reorder="reorderItem(item, $fromIndex, $toIndex)">
  </ion-reorder-button>

</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.shouldShowDelete = false;
$scope.shouldShowReorder = false;
$scope.listCanSwipe = true
});
```

Comment: You can design a list view using custom css  then  need to develop custom directive which will be available on event like on-swipe-left or on-swipe-right to delete or edit record.